# Android Studio : AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest

Here is my `AndroidManifest.xml` file, I'm getting two multiple root errors with `<uses-permission>` and `<application>` and I don't seem to know why. Can anyone help out to fix this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.codepath.rkpandey.flixster" />

<uses-permission
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Flixster">

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </application>
```

Comment: Typo. Remove the `/` from this line: `package="com.codepath.rkpandey.flixster" />`. Make sure you have a closing `</manifest>` tag at the very end of the file, too.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below syntax for internet permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

you're adding this "xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" in your permission tag which is causing issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're closing the manifest tag at the top. You should close it at the bottom instead.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.codepath.rkpandey.flixster" >

<uses-permission
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"
tools:ignore="WrongManifestParent" />


<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_descriptor"
android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:supportsRtl="true"
android:theme="@style/Theme.Flixster">

<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
 </application>
</manifest>
```

(Note the last line and how there is no / now at the end of the first manifest tag)